# scandir fail to open directory

Tags: php

I am having trouble with `scandir()`. I am trying to display the files in my `snaps`-directory on a page under the subdomain in my cloud.

This is the PHP I used.

```
$files = scandir('./snaps');
print_r($files);
```

and this is the error.

```
Warning: scandir(./snaps) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/u703778423/public_html/cloud/index.php on line 39

Warning: scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in /home/u703778423/public_html/cloud/index.php on line 39
```

I have no idea what else to do.

Answer (score 10):

You probably assume, that the current work directory is next to the script `scandir()` is written in, which (in many cases) isn't.

```
scandir(__DIR__ . '/snaps');
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that error, your snaps directory would have to have the absolute path of

```
/home/u703778423/public_html/cloud/snaps
```

Make sure that this is the correct location for the directory, and that the webserver has the rights to access it.

Comment: How do you know? It's not mentioned, where `./snaps` should be, but only, that `./snaps` is missing.

Comment: @KingCrunch: because the script's location is specified in the error message, and the path in scandir is `./snaps`.

Comment: Snaps is directly in the public_html.

Comment: @cody: then your're down one level too far. Try `../snaps` instead.

Comment: I get this: Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 4f17d7.png [3] => 7i4mhm.jpg [4] => 966kfn.zip [5] => a0d66f.png [6] => bm88g0.zip [7] => d0cg6i.png [8] => error_log [9] => ff9ihn.gif [10] => fmc7e6.zip [11] => ihhkhn.zip [12] => minecraft.exe )

Comment: There you go - That's a directory dump.

Comment: Is there anyway you could make it so you can click and view/download the files?

Comment: Simplest method is to just make that directory browseable. Otherwise you do a loop in php and output some html wrappers around each filename to add a link.

Comment: I would do that, but I will be uploading a lot of files there.

Answer (score 0):

First off you're trying to display a few files that will not render as images... ex. (.zip).

Also are you making sure you're not trying to display the first two index values " . " and " .. "? I'm thinking this part of your code might not be the issue...