# how would I get scandir to echo links to files

Tags: php, directory, scandir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scandir fail to open directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885717/scandir-fail-to-open-directory)

I fixed part of my `scandir()` problem, but I do not like the arrays. I want it to display the files that are uploaded and give links to them so you would be able to click the images and view them, or click zip files and download them. Problem is I have no idea how to do this.

```
<?php
 $files = scandir('../snaps'); 
 print_r($files);
 ?>
```

My `scandir` so far.

Comment: is this just another part of your previous question? if so, you should probably edit that

Comment: Neither do we, unless you post some code and explain what, exactly, you want to do (make believe we have no idea what you're trying to do; because that's precisely the case).

Comment: Code posted. That is the scandir function I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give more details it might help, I think this code will help for the links:

```
    <?php
$files = scandir('../snaps'); 

foreach($files as $file){ ?>
<a href="../<?php echo $file; ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></a>
<?
}
?>
```

This is a function to create the Zip files

```
    <?
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false, $distill_subdirectories = true) {
  //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
  if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
  //vars
  $valid_files = array();
  //if files were passed in...
  if(is_array($files)) {

    //cycle through each file
    foreach($files as $file) {
      //make sure the file exists
      if(file_exists($file)) {
          // echo 1;
        $valid_files[] = $file;
      }
    }
  }
  //if we have good files...
  if(count($valid_files)) {
    //create the archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
      return false;
    }
    //add the files
    foreach($valid_files as $file) {
        if ($distill_subdirectories) {
        $zip->addFile($file, basename($file) );
        } else {
        $zip->addFile($file, $file);
        }
        }
    //debug
    //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

    //close the zip -- done!
    $zip->close();


    //check to make sure the file exists
    //return file_exists($destination);
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$destination}");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($destination);
    //echo $destination;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

And this is the way you can call it:

```
    $files = scandir('../snaps');

    $to_zip = array();
    foreach($files as $file){
        if($file != "." AND $file !=".."){
            $to_zip[] = $folder . "/".$file;
        }
    } 

$zip = create_zip($to_zip, "test.zip", true);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u703778423/public_html/cloud/snaps.php on line 60

Comment: You have to be more detailed. Which of the codes were you trying? Also after the <?php echo $file ?> put the semicolon <?php echo $file;?>

Comment: I tried the top one. I do not need to make zip files.

Comment: did you try with the semicolon?

Comment: oh, I fixed it. Thanks! Would you happen to know how to center it so it just decends?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? But if you have more questions maybe open another question, and write an example! And maybe check the question as answered!

Comment: It does this: http://prntscr.com/di0k0 I would like it to descend in the center.

Comment: oh, and it thinks the files are in the root of my server. The files are located in /snaps/

Comment: For that just put html around it. Like  <?php echo $file . "<br />" ; ?> IF you have more questions then open another questions or try different html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function print_dir($dir) {
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        $files = array();
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        echo '<table>';
        foreach($files as $file) {
            echo '<tr><td style="border:none;"><a href="path/to/' . $file . '"><img src="images/icons/file.png" /></a></td><td style="font-size:18px; border:none; padding-top:28px"><a href="path/to/' . $file . '">' . $file_name . '</a></td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use glob too.

```
$files = glob('../snaps/*');

foreach($files as $f) {
  echo '<a href="'.$f.'">'.$f.'</a><br />';
}
```

That's a very simple example - you may want to check that the current item is not ".." or "." at each pass.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u703778423/public_html/cloud/snaps.php on line 41 :|

Comment: Fixed typo, give it whirl now.