# List all files in one directory PHP

Tags: php, list, directory

What would be the best way to list all the files in one directory with PHP? Is there a $_SERVER function to do this? I would like to list all the files in the usernames/ directory and loop over that result with a link, so that I can just click the hyperlink of the filename to get there. Thanks!

Comment: glob() or scandir() are obvious choices

Comment: could you give an example of a code that uses those functions, or explain more about them?

Comment: For examples and explanations - the documentation is really the best place to go... It's the official source...

Comment: Thats funny that the Stack Overflow "Do your homework" search didn't pick those documents up. Thanks!

Comment: `$temp_files = glob(__dir__.'/*'); foreach($temp_files as $file) {.............}`

Comment: `glob` in general is the better choice.

Comment: this works: https://halgatewood.com/free-php-list-files-in-a-directory-script

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Check this out : [readdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)
This bit of code should list all entries in a certain directory:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

---

**Edit**: miah's solution is much more elegant than mine, you should use his solution instead.

Comment: this works perfect too `$files = scandir($imgspath);
       $total = count($files);
       $images = array();
       for($x = 0; $x <= $total; $x++):
        if ($files[$x] != '.' && $files[$x] != '..') {
        $images[] = $files[$x];
        }        
       endfor;`

Comment: Use `glob()`  better!  http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: This might be a better solution when performance matter: [readdir-vs-scandir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692764/readdir-vs-scandir).

Comment: your advantage is: you can filter in one single loop. Say you only want to have `.html`  files and no files containing `404`, you can do this on one loop with your solution. Miah you have to loop over the results again

Answer (score 780):

You are looking for the command [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

```
$path    = '/tmp';
$files = scandir($path);
```

Following code will remove `.` and `..` from the returned array from `scandir`:

```
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
```

Comment: This is the more elegant solution.  I would also add/recommend $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.'));

Comment: Actually not `$files` but `$filesAndDirs`

Comment: @GustvandeWal on my experience, most of `scandir()` on my code and reviews used something like `foreach(scandir($x) as $file) if ($file selection) {...}`, and `glob()` not need the `if`, neither regular expressions or array_diffs for selection.

Comment: $files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'))); // this will reindex

Comment: I experienced a small snag finding the directory.
`$files = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__ .$path), array('.', '..'));` solved the problem. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885717/scandir-fail-to-open-directory

Comment: Use **array_values()** to reindex the array after **array_diff()**  `array_values(array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.')));`