# function which show all files and directories

Tags: php, dir

I tried to make function to show all files and dir(if have) in one selected dir.

```
class Test{

private $directory;

    public function getDir($directory){
            $this->directory = realpath($directory);
            $scan = scandir($this->directory);

            foreach ($scan as $value) {

                if(!is_dir($this->directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value)){
                    echo '<span style="color:blue">'.$value.'</span><br>';
                }else{
                    echo '<span style="color:red">'.$value.'</span><br>';
                    //Here I tried to return getDir($value) - but I retype $directory any ideas ?
                }
            }
        }
```

I thought over this how to make but ... Little help will be really nice.
                                                     Excuse my bad english.

Comment: Maybe if $directory is array, but I dont know ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php    or  http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php    or http://www.sitepoint.com/list-files-and-directories-with-php/   or   http://proger.i-forge.net/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80/PHP/[11.04.09]%20Recursively%20list%20all%20files%20in%20a%20directory.html

Comment: I know how to scan all files, but I want if one of the scaned files is dir to return function again.

Comment: one recursive way is also there in my given link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use recursive way :

```
<?php
...
private $result;

public function getDir($directory) {
    $files = scandir(realpath($directory));

    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = realpath($directory .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $value);
        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            $this->results[] = '<span style="color:blue">'.$value.'</span><br>';
        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            $this->getDir($path);
            $this->results[] = '<span style="color:red">'.$value.'</span><br>';
        }
    }

    return $this->results;
}
```