# retrieving certain contents from a directory

Tags: php, directory, file-get-contents

hello i'm not experienced in php so if anyone can help i would really appreciate it.

Okay so what i want to do is retrieve specific of an open directory.

the directory looks like this

http://pastebin.com/e6XvrWVK

I want to retrieve all the contents under 'Name' and 'last modified'

`ex: username1 : 02-Aug-2013 13:23`

I know you have to use file_get_contents but i'm just learning php and not experienced at all . 
I know this isn't a HQ Post but I would appreciate if anyone can help . Thanks!

Comment: There are many examples, sample code on SO and google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php https://www.google.com/search?q=php+read+directory&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't actually want to use `file_get_contents`, but actually want to use [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).