# Codeigniter Display "Index of Page" of Directory inside view

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

In Codeigniter php framework, I want to show directory files as Apache index of structure,

> domain.com/controller/index_directory

Adding View won't be working, as I need to show directory not view using controller,

Like above
[image: apache index of]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all files in one directory PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php)