# JavaScript or PHP: list all mp3 files from folder in HTML5

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get java-script or PHP code to read all mp3 files to my website so they can be played in the browser.
At the moment I have to program each file individually and this takes a long time so I'm trying to find a way so that my code reads from a folder with all of my mp3 files within it. This is an example of what i have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    audio 1
    <audio controls>
        <source src="audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    audio 2
    <audio controls>
        <source src="audio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Already voted this question as Too Broad, but also quickly found a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php  Which itself links to other duplicates.  In general, you should always start with Google.  It's *highly unlikely* that you're the first person to ever want to list files from a directory with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need PHP to do that, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

From PHP documentation :

```
    $handle = opendir('/path/to/files')

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        //Do something with $entry
    }


    closedir($handle);
```

A more easy way to do so is using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) :

```
foreach(glob('path/to/file/*.mp3') as $entry)
  //Do something with $entry
```

It also filters out non mp3 files

Comment: thanks, I used a similar piece of the code you linked and in the echo section i used this: ' <source src="mp3_files/$entry" type="audio/mpeg"> ' in the same format as my original post, in the browser it shows the correct number of files and the audio box but the length for each file is 0 seconds, could it be that ' $entry ' is being used wrong, and if so, how would it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe the path of your files is not the correct one, where is the page located relative to your mp3 files ?

Comment: the file that its being listed on is /index.php and the files are in /mp3_files/

Comment: when i type $entry in echo, it just displays `$entry` (not the actual name) in the browser with the audio box next to it

Comment: Ah I see your error, `$entry` is not evaluated in your string because is a simple quoted string, it should be a double quoted string, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php.  You should write `echo "<source src=\"$entry\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">";`