# jQuery-File-Upload - Show ONLY files starting with specific file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, file-upload

How can I set it to show only files starting with specific file name and not showing all files that are in the folder ??

EXAMPLE: Files that are in the folder:

```
1111_file1.jpg
1111_file2.jpg
2222_anotherfile.jpg
2222_anotherfile2.jpg
3333_anotherfile4.jpg
```

I want to show only the files starting with `1111_`

I am using the the AngularJS version found here [LINK](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)

The only thing I changed was I added a hidden input that will set the value for example: `<input type="hidden" name="wo" value="1111_">`

Here is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin AngularJS Demo
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Demo - AngularJS version</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for AngularJS. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing. Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css"></noscript>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
<style>
/* Hide Angular JS elements before initializing */
.ng-cloak {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-app="demo" data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
<input type="hidden" name="wo" value="1111_">     
     <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="error.asp"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
                </span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="submit()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped files ng-cloak">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-class="{'processing': file.$processing()}">
                <td data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-when="true">
                        <a data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery><img data-ng-src="{{file.thumbnailUrl}}" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-default data-file-upload-preview="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.url">
                        <span data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                            <a data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery>{{file.name}}</a>
                            <a data-ng-switch-default data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
                        </span>
                        <span data-ng-switch-default>{{file.name}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <strong data-ng-show="file.error" class="error text-danger">{{file.error}}</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="size">{{file.size | formatFileSize}}</p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active fade" data-ng-class="{pending: 'in'}[file.$state()]" data-file-upload-progress="file.$progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="file.$submit()" data-ng-hide="!file.$submit || options.autoUpload" data-ng-disabled="file.$state() == 'pending' || file.$state() == 'rejected'">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="file.$cancel()" data-ng-hide="!file.$cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-ng-controller="FileDestroyController" type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy" data-ng-click="file.$destroy()" data-ng-hide="!file.$destroy">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-xBuQ/xzmlsLoJpyjoggmTEz8OWUFM0/RC5BsqQBDX2v5cMvDHcMakNTNrHIW2I5f" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js" integrity="sha384-r6jjWwxAypHaESwS5an5J9dkfzwQuKVNV9FZM9B6fnt8PFuY0cVwLhV7BltCZhLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload Angular JS module -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if the URL is `&startingwith=1111_` it would only show files that start with `1111_`

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to hide non-matching files from the client-side _only_. So, probably you have to use some server-side code. For that, you should specify what kind of server are you using.

Comment: Can we get a useable demo to work with?

Comment: Hi @rv7 but how is js displaying all those files ? I find it hard to believe that I cannot loop over those results and get the ones I dont need not to show-up

Comment: @Deckerz There is a posted LINK (see above) that was a working example

Comment: @compcobalt thats a demo site, not a fiddle with changeable code

Comment: Checkout [this](https://jsfiddle.net/monim67/v61eoL8d/).

Comment: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/monim67/v61eoL8d/1/) one reloads after 5 seconds. If this is what you are looking for I will post answers.

Comment: Have you checked the links?

Comment: are you talking about the file browse dialog?  If so, that's outside of the DOM.   You can only set extension filter.  See this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can check files being uploaded for valid filenames using JS. I have created following function that checks if filename uploaded starts with "1111_" or not.

```js
 function checkFileForValidFilename()
    {
        var fileUploadID = document.getElementById("fileUploadID");
        var aryFiles = fileUploadID.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < aryFiles.length; i++)
        {
            var fileName = aryFiles[i].name.startsWith("1111_");
         if(!fileName)
                alert("Please upload file with name starting with 1111_");
            else
                alert("Done.");
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id="fileUploadID" type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="checkFileForValidFilename();" />
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Hi, I need to filter out the existing files to show files that start with "1111_" only

Comment: Do you have an array of file names? Or do you have the path where the files are uploaded/stored?

Comment: Its all from the file in \server\php\UploadHandler.php it posts the file to a directory called files

Comment: Check out this answer that uses PHP to list files in a directory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774702/8478475 will this work? And then you can make validations to only allow certain type of files. Let me know if I understood well.