# PHP / html web app to browse and open files

Tags: php, html, web-services, connection, localhost

I am new to the web app development and server topics so my question is rather theoretical. I’ve searched and went through a lot of related topics but haven’t found any satisfying answer and explanation:

Lately I was trying to write a rather simple PHP/html web app to display the content of my local dir let’s say C:/Users/Desktop and generate hyperlinks that would redirect me to the subfolders (and ideally open files in it)
I tried a lot of ready solutions but they were very outdated (3 or 4 years ago) then I found out that it is impossible on all web browsers because of security reasons. From what I learned it is only possible when browsing files on a server but I don’t really know how to enable it locally on my PC.

Could anyone explain to me why it is so? Or if it’s any way to pass it?

Thanks in advance, best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily install a local server (including php runtime) on your PC, like https://www.apachefriends.org or http://www.wampserver.com

A simple guide: https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/

List files: [List all files in one directory PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php)