# Which Javascript I need for a carousel with random photos from specific folder?

Tags: javascript, css, random, carousel, slideshow

I have a problem that seems small, but it is no longer making me sleep at night, I am probably thinking about it too much and I have lost sight of the correct path!

I'm using Bootstrap 4 as Framework. I have to insert an automatic, interaction-free, full-page Carousel that displays images in random order each time the page is refreshed. It has to get the images from a specific folder, because I have a large number of images.

Anyone can help me with the Javascript that i need for do that??

below the piece of basic code from which I start. Obviously written like this works without problems, and reflects the style I need, but the images are always the same, and in the order indicated.

Thanks in advance

```
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Big+Shoulders+Stencil+Text&family=Big+Shoulders+Text&family=Goldman&family=Heebo&family=Quicksand&family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style media="screen">
        .carousel-inner > .carousel-item {
            min-height: 800px;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="nopadding">
        <div id="carouselProjRec" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" interval="1800">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/car4.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item active transparent" style="background-image: url(img/car3.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/car8.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/car7.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/car6.jpg)">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/car11.jpg)">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, reading data from a directory isn't supported in JavaScript. You might need a server side language like PHP or Node JS to read the directory and add them in HTML.

For example, if it's PHP, you can do something like [List all files in one directory PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php). You can use that array to build your array:

```php
<?php
  foreach($files as $file) {
    echo '<div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/' . $file . ')"></div>';
  }
```

Or if you're using Node JS, it's still simpler:

```js
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
//passsing directoryPath and callback function
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 
    //listing all files using forEach
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the file
        console.log('<div class="carousel-item transparent" style="background-image: url(img/' + file + ')"></div>'); 
    });
});
```

Ultimately you need a server side language for this.

Comment: oh, ok....I thought it was easier and you could create a JS dedicated to reading the specific folder!
Unfortunately I don't know PHP and JS is also very limited.
thank you so much for your feedback anyway.
Maybe someone can find another solution ...

Comment: @DamV I don't think there's anything else. But feel free to accept it after couple of days! Have a nice day.

Comment: banging my head against the wall I solved it, lol.

This JS I solved the problem and it seems to work !!

Comment: @DamV But you're not getting it from JavaScript. You're hard-coding it. If you wanna do that, that's easier. Above JavaScript is what you need from `// listing all files using forEach`. You said with the JavaScript alone you wanna access the filesystem not an array!

Answer (score 0):

This JS is working..

```
<div class="container-fluid nopadding" style="width:100vw; min-height: 400px;">

<script language="javascript">
  var delay=1500 //set delay in miliseconds
  var curindex=0

  var randomimages=new Array()

    randomimages[0]="img/car1.jpg"
    randomimages[1]="img/car5.jpg"
    randomimages[2]="img/car2.jpg"
    randomimages[3]="img/car4.jpg"
    randomimages[4]="img/car3.jpg"
    randomimages[5]="img/car6.jpg"

  var preload=new Array()

  for (n=0;n<randomimages.length;n++)
  {
    preload[n]=new Image()
    preload[n].src=randomimages[n]
  }

  document.write('<img width="100%" height="100%" class="img-size" <img name="defaultimage" src="'+randomimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length))]+'">')

  function rotateimage()
  {

  if (curindex==(tempindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomimages.length)))){
  curindex=curindex==0? 1 : curindex-1
  }
  else
  curindex=tempindex

    document.images.defaultimage.src=randomimages[curindex]
  }

  setInterval("rotateimage()",delay)

</script>

 <!--  Random image slideshow - Thanks to Tyler Clarke (tyler@ihatecoffee.com)
  For this script and more, visit http://www.javascriptkit.com -->
```

Comment: _It has to get the images from a specific folder, because I have a large number of images._ Your code doesn't do it. It just loops from an array, which is totally different from what you asked.