# How to set php varible set in php and get filenames fromfolder

Tags: javascript, php, html

how do i get a list of all the filenames of files in C:\xampp\htdocs\dump\uploads in php varible them get the value of php varible in js

Comment: You need [get all files in a directory php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php) then [pass variable from php to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi i got all files in a directory but i cant pass the varible i have tryed all ways listed in the wuestion u linked

Comment: Yes there are a ways to do that and I answer with *JSON way*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Serverside**
Read the files.

```
$files = [];
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $files[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Render the page and echo $files in script tag. like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const files = JSON.parse(<?php echo "'".json_encode($files)."'"; ?>);    
    console.log('myFiles', files); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable from PHP to JS
First you need to know that PHP is rendered on server side; However JS is executed on client side; So a way to send vars from PHP to JS is using `JSON`

```html
<!-- In your file of PHP you have: -->
<!-- some code of php to generate variable of all your files... -->
<?php $files = ['dir1','file1.txt','img.jpg']; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- here inside the same file you have your script js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // call your variable with format JSON
    var filesJSON = <?php echo "'".json_encode($files)."'"; ?>;
    console.log(JSON.parse(filesJSON)); //['dir1', 'file1.txt', 'img.jpg']
</script>
</body>
</html>
```